# Flutter: Top right floating button onTap in iPhone 14 pro max doesn't work

Tags: flutter

I have following codes

```
Widget build() {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        body: Obx(
          () => SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                GoogleMap(
                  markers: Set<Marker>.of(controller.allMarkers),
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  initialCameraPosition: controller.initialLocation,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController gmcontroller) async {
                    // -----  other codes here
                  },
                ),
                Positioned(
                    bottom: 10, child: productSlider()),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.35),
            child: InkWell(
              splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
              child: Icon(Icons.close,
                  color: Colors.white, size: 17),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

**The problem:**

In iPhone 14 pro Max, the floating button is Aligned `topRight`. The `onTap` property of Inkwell doesn't work if button is aligned all the way to the top (on the same line as island notch).

But when same floating button is aligned `bottomRight`, the tap works pretty well.

Is there anyway we can fix the issue?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use floatingActionButtonLocation property?